# Huawei System Manager class name retrieve for a specific screen/activity

Tags: android, android-intent, huawei-mobile-services

I want to load **ignore battery optimization** menu from an activity programmatically on Huawei device with android nougat. In android Lolipop/Marshmellow huawei devices, I can go to **Protected Apps** menu directly with following snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

for Android Nougat Huawei device, how can I retrieve the class path for **Ignore Battery optimization** like the 'Protected apps'?

Answer (score 0):

the ignore battery optimization menu can be retreived by the **ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS** action on Huawei nougat devices

```
intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```